# Proving $[a,b]$ is closed by proving the complement is open

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I'm using this definition: a subset $A$ of $\mathbb{R}$ is called open if $$ \forall x \in A, \exists \delta > 0: ]  x - \delta, x + \delta [ \subset A. $$

Now, I need to prove that $[a,b]$ is closed, by proving that $X = \mathbb{R} \setminus [a,b] = ]- \infty, a [ \cup ]b, + \infty [$ is open.

**Attempt at proof:** Let $x \in X$ be arbitrary. Then we need to find a $\delta > 0$ such that $]  x - \delta, x + \delta [ \subset X$. We have two cases. Either $x \in ]- \infty, a [$ or $x \in ]b, + \infty [$. In the first case we take $ 0 < \delta \leq a-x$, in the second case we take $0 < \delta \leq x - b$.

Now, I need to prove that in both cases $]  x - \delta, x + \delta [ \subset X$ and this is where it goes wrong. Let $y \in ]  x - \delta, x + \delta [$ be arbitrary. Then $y > x - \delta \geq x - (a-x) = 2x-a$ and $y < x + \delta \leq x + (a - x) = a$. So we have $2x - a < y < a$. Can I now conclude from this that $y \in X$ ?? The fact that $y < a$ is ok, but what about the lower bound?

Comment: Why should you care about the lower bound? You just need $y<a$ for all $y \in ]x-\delta, x+\delta[$. Just say $y<x+\delta \leq a$. Everything is correct, though.

Comment: When you choose $y< m$ you can't do $y>n$ with $m\le n$. That's a little confusion

Comment: Think about $\delta$ as arbitrarily small, by example you can think ever some rational number that is smaller than anyone, so any $x$ that is inside some interval is rounded by infinite small rational (or irrational) numbers... no matter what $x$ you get.

Answer (score 2):

You're overcomplicating it. In the first case, if $y \in (x-\delta,x+\delta)$ then $y < x+\delta \le a$, so $y\in (-\infty, a)$. Similarly for the second case: if $y\in (x-\delta,x+\delta) \subseteq (b,+\infty)$, then $b \le x-\delta < y$, so $y\in (b,+\infty)$.